# php check getvalue is not null

Tags: php, arrays

I get this output as an array $vcard:

```
object(Sabre\VObject\Component\VCard)#11987 (6) {
  ["children":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["EMAIL"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>"mail@domain.de"
    }
   }
}
```

With this code I get the value of EMAIL:

```
echo $vcard->EMAIL->getvalue()
```

The problem: If the key "EMAIL" doesn't exist I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: EMAIL
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getvalue() on
> null

How can I handle this error?

Comment: It'd be `$vcard->children['EMAIL']` if I'm not wrong, but `children` is protected. Where does `getvalue()` come from exactly? A `var_dump()` display won't show methods.

Comment: I'm using this lib: https://github.com/mstilkerich/carddavclient

Comment: Fix the first error first, that will in turn help you solve the second error.

Answer (score 0):

It works !

```
if($email = $vcard->EMAIL) {
   echo $vcard->EMAIL->getValue();
} else {
   echo "NOT OK";
}
```